# Why does the value change based on whether or not I print a value in the constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, cout

Given the following C++ code segment, the behavior and output is as expected:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    int n;
    int *p;
    A(int n);
};

A::A(int n) {
    this->n = n;
    this->p = &n;
    cout << *(this->p) << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    A a(55);
    cout << a.n << endl;
    cout << *(a.p) << endl;
}
```

The output is:

```
55
55
55
```

But when the print line in the constructor is commented out, this is the result:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    int n;
    int *p;
    A(int n);
};

A::A(int n) {
    this->n = n;
    this->p = &n;
    // cout << *(this->p) << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    A a(55);
    cout << a.n << endl;
    cout << *(a.p) << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
55
32767
```

I realize that 32767 is not an arbitary number, as it is (2^15)-1, but why does the value printed by the final `cout` statement of the main method change based on whether that line in the constructed is commented out or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
this->p = &n;
```

`n` here resolves to the parameter to the constructor. This sets `p` to point to the argument to the constructor, and ***not*** the class member. When the constructor terminates, `p` points to a destroyed object (the constructor parameter value), and dereferencing `p` is undefined behavior.

This is one argument against using the same names for the constructor's parameters as the names of class members that are getting initialized. Makes it easy to unintentionally create undefined behavior.

Change this to:

```
this->p = &this->n;
```

to get the expected results.

Answer (score 4):

This line:

```
    this->p = &n;
```

means "set `this->p` to point at the local variable `n`". Which is perfectly fine, except that the local variable goes out of scope immediately afterward, after which point any attempt to dereference `p` invokes "undefined behavior" (because it points to memory that is no longer properly allocated). This means that the program is allowed to do absolutely anything, up to and including growing a fist and shaking it at you menacingly. (Fortunately, no major compilers support that kind of biotechnology yet.)

If you run the same experiment on a different compiler, you will likely see a different result, as it's quite random.

---

I'm guessing that you instead meant to write

```
    this->p = &(this->n);
```

so that it instead points to the *member* `n`?